# Instanced Geometry Nodes not moving with Rig

Tags: armature, geometry-nodes, proxies

I'm quite the Blender Newbie and tried to instance some objects on my character. I used a Switch Node for that, but now am struggling to make the instances move with the Characters Armature ( on image1 I deactivated the other instances for clarity ).

[image: Instanced Spiral Object]

The object that is using the Switch Node is bound to the rig and moving, but after using the Switch the mesh doesn't move with the armature anymore.
The instance keeps its transform and I tried to change it by setting the position with its Original position, but it's not working unfortunately.

[image: Instance stays in place]

[image: Static Mesh Example]

This was the original setup before my failed attempts to fix the positioning.

[image: Initial Node Setup]

Maybe someone has an idea on how to fix this or some tips.

Thank you!

__
**Edit** I have added the [Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FMVjv0igC4o-_LFcOPBe_8UV9GP-TZLL/view?usp=sharing), so its easier to see what's going on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have parented your GN object (Spiralproxy.012) to the armature as object parenting.
But you have to use another parenting type e.g. bone. I show you here, how you can repair it, but of course you should choose another bone or way.

[image]

You have to be crystal clear about what parenting means:

Parenting to an object just moves and rotates the parented object with its parent. So if you move the whole armature (as object) it would move with it.
Parenting to bones means, it moves with the bone.

Comment: Oh thank you so much, this helped a lot! I thought the parenting with Weights would make the difference already, nice to know :)
When you say choose another bone or way to repair do you mean that this wouldn't be the best/ most elegant way to solve this or rather just pick a specific bone?

Comment: I have a question. How do I parent multiple (30-40) Instances, that are placed all over the body-surface to the closest bone? (Its kind of an armor) (I can't do it manually for each instance separatly)

Comment: @Mechandrius: please do not ask in comments. Why not? because nobody can learn from your question and the answer in comments because the search in BSE doesn't consider comments. Just open a new question (you can open as many as you like) - thx.

Answer (score 0):

Your geometry nodes modifier has to be after the armature modifier (under in the modifiers stack).

Comment: Thank you :) I tried that now, but the Mesh seems to stay at the Origin Point where it's instantiated :/